# gcloud deployment manger - using snapshot as <sourceImage>

Tags: deployment, google-compute-engine, gcloud

Questions regarding Google cloud deployments using deployment-manager:

1)Is it possible to use a snapshot as the  for a REPLICA_POOL deployment template ?

2)If so, how does the "zone" of the snapshot affect the deployment zone? In other words, can i mount a snapshot of us-central-a to a europe-west1-a?

3)What would be the sourceImage Url for snapshot?

Your input/comments would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ha! Exactly what i wanted to do...
https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/images#creating_an_image_from_a_root_persistent_disk